# Flex: Placing items on the canvas element

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am writing simple game on flex. In the game there are 2 objects Board and Stone (both are extended from the Canvas super class)

When I started to place Stones instances to the Board Canvas, I come across the problem, I can't understand how to set Stone on the defined position on the board.

So if for example board (canvas) has following attributes: x = 25, y = 25, height = 100, width = 100

How can I for example place a Stone (canvas) in a point 25, 25.

Is there a way to use local board coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
board.addChild(stone);
stone.x = 25;
stone.y = 25;
```

Btw, you need not use `Canvas` for these objects - a Shape or Sprite would be enough. Add the Board sprite to the flex app using `rawChildren.addChild(board);` Canvas is a Container class for flex ui components.

Comment: Thank you again! Will try sprite. Should I use it for both board and stone objects?

Comment: yeah, Flex components are for UI development - they have a lot of inbuilt functionalities for that purpose. Why waste them if all you want is moving circles on a board?

Comment: Will try. What I am thinking of, is leave board as it is (Canvas class), and implement stones, as Sprites. Will try this solution today, and then will post if it worked fine with me... Thanks again